# page is being refreshed instead of loading the assigned url

Tags: javascript, jquery, href, keypress

I'm trying to catch 'enter' key on an input textbox and then assign a new url to my page based on the input. The problem is that the link assigned to `windoe.location.href` is somehow being overwritten by the current value for `windoe.location.href` and the page is being refreshed instead of loading the new url assigned.

Here is the code:

```
  $(this).on('keydown', function(event) {
       myKeyCode=event.which
       if(myKeyCode==13) //'enter' key pressed
       {
          link=window.location.origin + '/search?search=' + $(this).val();
          window.location.href=link;
       }
  });
```

I'm guessing that some default behavior from `keypress` event is interfering.
I have tried preventing the default behavior using `event.preventDefault();` but that prevents the input textbox from taking any input.

Another weird observation: the code behaves just fine when I put an `alert('something');` between the two lines inside my if-statement. It seems like the

```
window.location.origin + '/search?search=' + $(this).val();
```

is taking a while to be evaluated and using alert would give it enough time to evaluate.

Comment: Put `event.preventDefault()` as the first line in `if` block. Some browsers submit the form when `ENTER` is pressed.

Comment: @Teemu that would prevent anything from being typed in the input box, you need to put it `inside` of the `if` for it to stop the default action when the enter key is pressed.

Comment: @Teemo `event.preventDefault()` prevents the textbox from taking any inputs.

Comment: @Greenish It doesn't, if it's executed only when `ENTER` is pressed.

Comment: Oh Sorry @Teemu. I had commented on your previous comment I guess. Putting `event.preventDefault()` inside if-statement works fine!
Awesome!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if (myKeyCode==13) {
  event.preventDefault();
  link=window.location.origin + '/search?search=' + $(this).val();
  window.location.href=link;
}
```

Comment: So preventing the default after 'enter' is pressed would make sure that the default behaviors are prevented after the input is entered.
awesome guys!